# &nbsp not working in comments

Tags: comments, html

In WordPress comments spacing are not working. When i am using `&nbsp` in comments for spacing, WordPress showing these as it is on front end. Other html tags are working but this one is not working. 
Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: The correct tag is `&nbsp;`, does this work?

Comment: Working perfectly '&nbsp;'. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong code. Use `&nbsp;`
[HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)